# create header row and index column pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am importing a matrix of this kind:

```
0  1  0  0  0 -1  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  0
0  0 -1  0  1  0  0
```

I would like to add a header row and an index column so that it looks the following way:

```
   e1 e2 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
y1 0  1  0  0  0 -1  0
y2 0  1  0  1  0  0  0
y3 0  0 -1  0  1  0  0
```

I have been trying hard with the pgfplots table, but I have not achieved anything useful.

Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: If the first line contains data or [header=false], the columns will be accessed by index number, e.g [index] 0.  You can assign names using /columns/{[index]0}/.style={column name=...}

Comment: You will need to create a new column (probably as a comma delimited list) for the "row names". and assign it an empty column name.

Comment: Regarding the first comment I am not sure where I have to put the command. Should it go here?

\pgfplotstabletypeset[/columns/{[index]1}/.style={column name=hla}]\connectivitytable

Comment: As for the second comment I know how to create a new column however it would be better if one could create the names in a loop because of being concatenated.

Comment: In all the examples, there is already a column containing 1,2,3,... One can create a comma delimited list using a foreach loop and \xdef.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317347/specify-xtick-ytick-with-multiplication-in-pgfplots/317380?s=5|11.5962#317380 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Feel free to add more rows or columns in*

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
0  1  0  0  0 -1  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  0
0  0 -1  0  1  0  0
}\test

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\test}
\pgfmathsetmacro\LastRow{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\test}
\pgfmathsetmacro\LastColNo{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{document}
Old: \pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.style={output empty row}]{\test} 
\bigskip

% Specify head row
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1} {%
\pgfplotstableset{
columns/#1/.style = {column name=$e_{\pgfmathparse{int(#1+1)} \pgfmathresult}$},
}}%

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,\LastColNo} {%
\pgfplotstableset{
columns/#1/.style = {column name=$x_{\pgfmathparse{int(#1-1)} \pgfmathresult}$},
}}%

% Create new column
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/newcol/.style={
create col/set list={1,...,\LastRow}
},
columns/newcol/.style={column name={},
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=$y_{##1}$}
},
}

New: \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={newcol,0,1,...,\LastColNo},
column type=r,   %string type, 
]{\test}
\end{document}
```